# Can I install a new 30A breaker in an empty slot in 125A panel?

Tags: electrical, workshop

I got one of these [Wen #3403 Dust Collectors](https://wenproducts.com/collections/dust-management/products/1500-cfm-16-amp-5-micron-woodworking-dust-collector-with-50-gallon-collection-bag-and-mobile-base) as a Christmas gift and I'm wondering if hooking it up is a matter of installing a new breaker and running a 10/2 line to the garage. I have air conditioners and pool equipment, etc. already hooked up, but no other appliances except smaller 15 and 20A things.

[It says in one place](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0012/0350/3168/files/3403.manual.20180703.pdf?7297136212241545631) that it needs 110V an 25A breaker, and in another that it needs a  30A breaker. It seems to run at 12-16A, but I imagine needs some extra for starting up.

I've read that code requires it to be hard-wired with a switch. Is that true? What's the harm in using the plug for occasional use, etc. Also, since it's a garage, do I need a GFCI outlet?

Comment: The manual clearly states *higher than* 25A. That rounds to a 30. It mentions 25 elsewhere only as a warning to installers when working with high-current device wiring.

Comment: **25A** (in the US at least) is an automatic "not your regular circuit" indicator. The ordinary 110V circuits are all 15A and 20A. Once you get past that, it generally means a bigger breaker **and** thicker wire **and** the right kind of receptacle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first page of the manual indicates a CSA listing, which due to treaty bears the same weight as UL.  So you have to follow the instructions.  The listing is contingent on doing what the instructions say.

So yes, a 10/2 cable with 30A *(greater than 25)* breaker to a solitary single NEMA 5-20 socket, labeled for this one appliance, is what's called for.  This is a special socket that should not be used for any other appliance, unless that other appliance also specifies a "greater than 25A" breaker.

If you want to also support other circuits, then throw in a 10/3 and install a subpanel. Bonus points if it's a GFCI hot tub panel, because that will answer the GFCI requirements on any garage circuit.  Preferably a GE type that supports their weird 1/2" breakers because then you can use "double stuff" breakers for density and still customize the breaker size for each load.

By the way, you can't ordinarily bump breaker sizes in response to nuisance tripping.  You can do it here, because of a special motor rule, and because the instructions said so *because of the special motor rule*.

Comment: I don't think that I'd need to use other circuits on there, but is it OK to add additional NEMA 5-20R 20-amp outlets... so that I could move the equipment to different sides of the garage, etc?

Comment: Yes, for that purpose.

Comment: I seem to only be able to find 5-20R 20A outlets.... don't they make 30A ones?

Comment: 5-30R's should be a thing.  If not you can use TT30.

Comment: Those don't seem to physically match the plug on the end of the cord. Unit instructions call for 5-20R....
"The tool has a built-in 25A overload protector to protect the motor. To prevent tripping your electrical circuit, the fuse rating of your circuit must be 
HIGHER than 25A. The power plug should be plugged into a matching NEMA 5-20R outlet as shown in Fig. A, with a fuse rating higher than 25A. 
Only one machine should be connected to a dedicated circuit. Always 
check local code for wiring outlets that are 25 amps and above."